# Combining two tables with some blank information in Access/SQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I’m new to SQL and I’m using MS Access 2016. I created a query using **Table1** and **Table2**.

**Table1** holds the data `A, B, C, D.`
**Table2** holds values (the letters are T2Data1; and numbers are T2Data2): `A 2, A 6, B 3, & D 4.`

The query is:

```
SELECT Table1.T1Data1, Sum(Table2.T2Data2) AS SumOfT2Data2
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.T1Data1 = Table2.T2Data1
GROUP BY Table1.T1Data1;
```

Ideally I want the output to be:

```
A 8  
B 3  
C  
D 4
```

I can get `A, B, & D` but I can't get the blank for `C`. How do I do that?? Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Use an `outer join`:

```
SELECT Table1.T1Data1, Sum(Table2.T2Data2) AS SumOfT2Data2
FROM Table1 
    LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.T1Data1 = Table2.T2Data1
GROUP BY Table1.T1Data1
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)
- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e765c/2)

If you want to return 0 instead of null, you may need to use `nz()` which is similar to `coalesce`.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you.